Drying times for oil based polyurethane
I'm finishing a desk extention using quick dry, oil based, poly. I needed the amber effect of oil based to match the existing desk otherwise I would use water based for speed. I have 5 days before installation in a historic, government front office and computer equipment will be placed immediately on the desk so business can resume, but the between coat "quick-dry" time isn't as quick as the can suggests.
If I use the 50/50 polyurethane/mineral spirits method, applied with a cloth, what is the wait time between coats and full cure time,
or should I go another rout? I have one coat on but time is of the essence and the 6 hour dry time between coats is more like 24. Still tacky at 18.

Try posting on the woodworking forum for a quicker/ better answer. I have placed pieces out in the sun when I needed quicker drying.

It depends heavily on environmental conditions, as with most things in life. You've said nothing about that. Of most importance is airflow. Got a fan going? Then, temperature. Is it cool where you are?

It's nearly 100 outside with high humidity, I'm in ac set at 75

I'm in Fla. I get the humidity, but never found it an issue if the temp. was above dew point

Crank up a dehumidifier in the room this is in.

Ttime between coats is not necessarily the same thing as drying time.
